# How do I share a notion page to web using the Notion API?

Tags: notion-api, notion

While we are able to do it from notion dashboard like this: https://www.notion.so/help/public-pages-and-web-publishing#make-a-page-public

But I want to make a page public using the API. I was not able to find anything in the API docs. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Not possible at this time via api.  (I asked Notion  support directly).
Something like this might help,  it I have yet to test it.
https://shop.yudax.me/l/5d8d64632198423bb3a13b02192fa717?layout=profile